# Issue with ECS, load balancer and task definition with multiple containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an ECS service with a LoadBalancers attached and a Task definition.

Currently, the task definition has one container and the Load balancer of the service checks the health of that container.

```
  ECSService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      ...
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: container1
          ContainerPort: 8080
          TargetGroupArn: LoadBalancerTargetGroupARN
```

Everything works well. But, I added a side-car container (as part of the same task definition) which I don't need to health-check, and now both containers stop.
First, the new one (container2) with the message

```
Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:XXX:targetgroup/my-service-target/XXX)
```

And then, also the old one with

```
Task failed to start
```

Is there a way to prevent the Load Balancer of the Service from trying to check the status of the new container?

I will refactor the question if needed. Thanks.

Comment: You actually added the second container to `LoadBalancers` property with its own TG?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks as always. No. Under `AWS::ECS::Service` -> `LoadBalancers` I just have the `container1`, not `container2`. If I'm understanding you well.

Comment: So LB won't be checking its health. Maybe your first container fails due to the side-container, and this triggers health failure.

Comment: And do you know some resources that I can check? I'm following AWS docs for XRAY side-container for VPC task definition: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-ecs.html?icmpid=docs_xray_console